# How is the following arithmetic sequence solved?

Tags: arithmetic

Apologies to bother you with this, but how is the following arithmetic sequence solved?

> $$\dfrac1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{n-k+1}2\right)$$

Comment: I do not understand the notation at all.  Can you edit it into Latex format?

Comment: How to write math? For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), ...

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first time using this site. I will attempt to make this clearer

Comment: The left side seems to mean $$\sum_{k=1}^n k.$$ What is the right side?

Comment: In my basic terms, this formula is 1/n multiplied by Sigma of n-k+1 (numerator) divided by 2 (denominator). Where the term below sigma is K=1 and the term above is N-1

Comment: @user74185 I typeset in LaTeX. Does is it look right?

Comment: Yes thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

First, you can pull out everything from the sum that does not depend on $k$.  So $$\dfrac1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{n-k+1}2\right)=\frac 1n \left(\frac {(n-1)(n+1)}2-\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\right)$$ where I pulled out $\frac {n+1}2$ and multiplied by $n-1$ as the number of terms.  Can you do the last?

Comment: @P..:  I see.  Soon to fix

Comment: Apologies I still cannot use the correct math symbols, but I have this derivation as ((n-1)/2) - (1/2n) where this last term is multiplied by sigma K.

Comment: Does this sound correct. I need the final answer only in terms on n, so what would happen to the lone K now???

Comment: @user74185:  the $k$ is a dummy variable.  It represents all the values you are summing up.  Less formally, the last sum represents (without the leading $\frac 12$) $1+2+3+\ldots n-1$.  There is no $k$.  Have you seen that sum?  You might look at the triangular numbers.

Comment: So we completely drop the k, which would lead to the final solution I derived from your formula, which was ((n-1)/2) - (1/2n)

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$
\dfrac1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{n-k+1}2\right)=\dfrac{n}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}1-\dfrac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k+\dfrac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}1
$$
and see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).